# cross browser selector in Rails app

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I want to use `cross browser selector js` to solve my browser specific issues on my CSS.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'css_browser_selector' %>
```

here's how I am loading the js file under JS directory.

For IE10, one of my classes is not getting applied so here's how I am applying that using this `css browser selector`.

```
.ie10 .radio_packaging_white
  {
    border-image:url("/assets/border/white_border.png") 6 6 6 6; 
    border-image-width: 5px;
    min-height:165px;
    line-height:165px;
  }
```

But for some reason, It isn't working.

What's missing here?

Please help.